# PHP Show Merge data tables

Tags: php, mysql

Im sorry with the title, complicated to get the title. But try to read my statement below.

I want to merge data from table that had same name item but have a different information.
Table Example:

```
form_no | name     | status | date_added
1       | keyboard | OK     | 19-APR-2013 (today)
2       | keyboard | NG     | 18-APR-2013 (yesterday)
```

Now I want to show it in my page with just 1 information merge to be :
Table view Example :

```
No | Item Name | Yesterday Status | Today Status
1  | keyboard  | NG               | OK
```

Just it, I want to show it in table view with just 1 information merge. It has same name, but have different status based on date_added.

```
<table>
<td>Item Name</td><td>Yesterday Status</td><td>Today Status</td>
</table>

include ("includes/_db_.php");

$today = date("j-F-Y");
$yesterday = date("j-F-Y", time() - 60 * 60 * 24);

$query = "SELECT * from t_production_status";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $item_name = $data['name'];
    $status = $data['status'];
    $date_added = $data['date_added'];

<tr>
<td><?php echo $item_name; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $status; ?></td> <- this what I want show for yesterday status
<td><?php echo $status; ?></td> <- this what I want show for today status
<td><?php echo $date_added; ?></td>
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: [Don't use mysql_* extension](http://www.php.net/en/mysql_query). Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MSQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a self join on your status table..

```
SELECT status1, status2 FROM t_production_status status1 JOIN t_production_status status1
WHERE status1.name = status2.name
AND status1.date = (today)
AND status2.data = (yesterday)
```

(not tested, but It should be something along those lines)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html